# How to change the order of a List(Of Order) and do paging

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I need help with my code.

My goal is to be able to use the click event of two buttons to page through a list of orders. This list of orders, can also be re-sorted using a parameter passed via Query-string.

Currently I am able to do the paging, but not working 100% accurately.

For example, with my current code, if I have a list with the following order by email:

```
J.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
T.email.com
```

My paging code will browse the records as if they were in this order:

```
T.email.com - previous
J.email.com - current
R.email.com - next
R.email.com - next
R.@email.com - next
```

If I change the order to be descending:

```
T.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
J.email.com
```

The the paging code will begin like:

```
T.email.com
J.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
```

If I click previous when on record for 'T@email.com' then I get the page where user gets notified that there are no more records to browse to, but if I click the 'Next' button, then I go to the records for: 'J@email.com', but the entire set set and paging gets changed to:

```
T.email.com
J.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
R.email.com
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
Protected Sub btnUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUp.Click

Dim currentOrderID As String
Dim currentOrder As Order
Dim nextOrder As Order = Nothing

SiteKey = Request.QueryString("siteKey")
strEnv = Request.QueryString("strEnv")
currentOrderID = Request.QueryString("order_id")
strSortBy = Request.QueryString("SortBy")
strSortDirection = Request.QueryString("SortDirection")

orderList = New Orders(SiteKey)
orderList.GetOrdersByDate(CDate(Request.QueryString("Start")), CDate(Request.QueryString("End")).AddDays(1), strEnv)

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortBy) Then
    orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
End If

currentOrder = (From order In orderList.Items
                Where order.OrderID.Equals(currentOrderID)
                Select order).FirstOrDefault()

If currentOrder IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim index = orderList.Items.IndexOf(currentOrder)
    If Not index <= 0 Then _
        nextOrder = DirectCast(orderList.Items(index - 1), Order)
        If nextOrder IsNot Nothing Then
            btnUp.Visible = True
            Response.Redirect("~/order-review.aspx?order_id=" & nextOrder.OrderID & "&siteKey=" & SiteKey & "&strEnv=" & strEnv & "&Start=" & CDate(Request.QueryString("Start")) & "&End=" & CDate(Request.QueryString("End")) & "&SortBy=" & strSortBy &                                   "&SortDirection=" & strSortDirection)
        Else
            btnUp.Visible = False
            lblnoRecs.Visible = True
            lblnoRecs.Text = "No records to display. Click the Previous button to go to the next available order, or the link below to go to the search page."
            lnkgoBack.Visible = True
            lnkgoBack.Text = "Web"
            lnkgoBack.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/order-history.aspx?&siteKey=" & SiteKey & "&strEnv=" & strEnv & "&Start=" & Request.QueryString("Start") & "&End=" & Request.QueryString("End"))
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDown.Click

Dim currentOrderID As String = String.Empty
Dim previousOrder As Order = Nothing

SiteKey = Request.QueryString("siteKey")
strEnv = Request.QueryString("strEnv")
currentOrderID = Request.QueryString("order_id")
strSortBy = Request.QueryString("SortBy")
strSortDirection = Request.QueryString("SortDirection")

orderList = New Orders(SiteKey)
orderList.GetOrdersByDate(CDate(Request.QueryString("Start")), CDate(Request.QueryString("End")).AddDays(1), strEnv)

Dim temporders As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Order) = orderList.Items

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortBy) Then
    orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
End If

Dim currentOrder = (From order In orderList.Items
                    Where order.OrderID.Equals(currentOrderID)
                    Select order).FirstOrDefault()

If currentOrder IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim index = orderList.Items.IndexOf(currentOrder)
    If Not index >= orderList.Items.Count - 1 Then _
       previousOrder = DirectCast(orderList.Items(index + 1), Order)
       If previousOrder IsNot Nothing Then
           btnDown.Visible = True
           Response.Redirect("~/order-review.aspx?order_id=" & previousOrder.OrderID & "&siteKey=" & spiderSiteKey & "&strEnv=" & strEnv &"&Start=" & CDate(Request.QueryString("Start")) & "&End=" & CDate(Request.QueryString("End")) & "&SortBy=" & strSortBy & "&SortDirection=" & strSortDirection)
        Else
            btnDown.Visible = False
            lblnoRecs.Visible = True
            lblnoRecs.Text = "No records to display. Click the Next button to go to the next available order, or the link below to go to the search page."
            lnkgoBack.Visible = True
            lnkgoBack.Text = "Web"
            lnkgoBack.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/order-history.aspx?&siteKey=" & SiteKey & "&strEnv=" & strEnv & "&Start=" & Request.QueryString("Start") & "&End=" & Request.QueryString("End"))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If there are not sort parameters for property, and direction, then this code should be ignored:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortBy) Then
    orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
End If
```

Is it possible I can get some guidance to correct this code?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I tried re-assigning the list of orders once they got re-sorted:

```
orderList = orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
```

But I get an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in 
App_Web_order-review.ascx.cc671b29.h0sxd1rw.dll but was not handled in user 
code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Order]' to type 'Orders'.
```

**UPDATE**

I had to convert to list, example:

```
orderList.Items = orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection).ToList
```

I think the order of how pagination occurs is still incorrect though. Like described in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderby returns a collection so you should save it:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortBy) Then
    orderList = orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
End If
```

Comment: (clarification to Keith Mifsuds answer) ...you should save it within a lazy getter of a property, and if the sortby or the direction changes, assign nothing to the orderList variable.

Comment: @Keith Mifsud, I tried your recommendation but I get an error. I added it as an update to the post. Many thanks.